# How to stretch image across full width of screen bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to stretch an image across a div using CSS and bootstrap. I tried making the div and parent container each fluid, which helped, but no matter what I do there is always some white space on the left and right sides of the image.

HTML

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row color-block-top"></div>

    <div class="row-fluid block">
      <img src="Images/family-beach.jpg" alt="Family on the beach" class="beach">
    </div>

    <div class="row color-block-top"></div>

  </div>
```

CSS

```
.color-block-top {
  background-color: rgb(36,54,138);
  padding: 1vh;
  min-width: 20em;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  object-fit: fill;
  width: 100%;
}

.beach {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)  properly by adding `col` as children of `row`, then you can use [spacing class utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/), in this case `px-0` to `container-fluid` to remove the default padding of it.

And to remove gutters you can use [gutters class utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) add `gx-0` to `row`s

```css
.color-block-top {
  background-color: rgb(36, 54, 138);
  height: 5vh
}
.beach {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid px-0">
  <div class="row gx-0 color-block-top"></div>
  <div class="row gx-0">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="Family on the beach" class="beach w-100 h-100 ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row gx-0  color-block-top"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This definitely helped, thanks for the assistance. 1 question, however. it is making my image really big now - not an issue as far as width, but how do I scale down the height? When I set h-50 it scales down the width but there is a big blank spot underneath the div.

Comment: if you want full width with fixed height it's normal to have blank space below. but when you set `h-50` you are setting `hsight:50%` maybe you want a different height value

Comment: Gotcha. I think I figured it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since you also don't typically need to create many of your own styling classes if any while utilizing bootstrap snippets and docs library, it's not a sin to create a special class to accommodate your grid layout. It's been months since you've asked so I'm guessing you're aware of this by now but you never know!

You add an opening and closing style tag between your head and body tag (e.g. if height set to 60% would have fit perfectly in your scenario, as that is not an included height percentage in bootstrap). And sometimes you need that size more than once making it handy to not have to occasionally give a bunch of divs long lists of class names in HTML.

This is added like so:

```
    <head>

    </head>

       <style>

       .h-60 {
          height: 60%
       }

       </style>


      <body>
```

Alternatively; given the element's parent has a specified value, setting the height class to "height: inherit" is also a nice option when it's available. A parent's size is defined in absolute values (e.g. height: 50px), then "height: inherit" or "height: 100%" will have the same behavior for the child.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).